Stripe: IntegrationError: You cannot have multiple Embedded Checkout objects
I'm using react-stripe-js and getting an IntegrationError: You cannot have multiple Embedded Checkout objects. This error occurs when trying to render the form more than once.
I think I need to destroy the checkout form somehow before creating a new instance, but I can't find how to do this within react-stripe-js.
Someone recommended using a different key for the EmbeddedCheckoutProvider, but that didn't resolve the issue.
<div id="checkout">
  <EmbeddedCheckoutProvider stripe={stripePromise}>
      <EmbeddedCheckout />
    </EmbeddedCheckoutProvider>
  </div>


It sounds like you need to remove the element from the DOM.  You shouldn't need to use any special method from react-stripe-js, just regular React.

@RyanM, I tried to clear it inside useEffect return document.getElementById("checkout").innerHTML = "". it didn't help

@RyanM, I think it's not about DOM element

You probably call an API which returns the clientSecret which is used to open the Stripe Embedded form right so you just have to set that clientSecret to null which will remove the Stripe checkout session.
